# Stringstream tellg is zero

Tags: c++, macos-catalina

I am working on some file reading and writing. I am reading a file like this:

```
std::stringstream file;
std::fstream stream;
stream.open(fileName, std::fstream::in);
file << stream.rdbuf();
stream.close();
```

The problem is, that calling `tellg()` on `file` returns 0 but the `str()` function returns the real content of the file without problems.

As far as I know this code has worked in the past, before I updated my OS from MacOS 10.14 to 10.15.4 so maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you were using `tellg()` and not `tellp()`?

Comment: `tellg()` returns the *input* position - which you haven't changed in the code you've shown. As @Eljay suggests, maybe you want `tellp()` to get the *output* position?

Comment: This solved the problem, I can't remember changing the code but who knows.